# How can i add codeowner specific to a branch name

Tags: git, github

I am trying to add one set of codeowners if the branch name starts with "testing/** " and another set of codeowners if branch name starts with "qa/** ". Is it possible to achieve this.

I tried creating codeowners but right now it will add reviewers based on the changes to files/directories in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

[Code owners](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) on GitHub are using a `CODEOWNERS` file which lists paths/files, not branches.

You can override that file content when creating a testing branch or a qa branch, but that would be a manual process.
Or one you could automate through a [GitHub `create-branch` Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-branch) where you can implement the `CODEOWNERS` file content modification.